# Replace ^M with <space> in all lines of a file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a log file with ^M embedded throughout.  I would like to replace the ^M with a single space.
I have tried variations on this:

```
(Get-Content C:\temp\send.log) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "^M", ' '} | Set-Content C:\temp\send.out
```

The output file contains a newline where each ^M had been, not at all what I was looking for...
The problem I am trying to solve involves examining the last $cnt lines of the file:

```
$new = Get-Content $fn | Select-Object -Last $cnt;
$new
```

When I display $new, the ^M are interpreted as CR/LF.
How can I remove/replace the ^M?  Thanks for any pointers....

Comment: Sorry to be *that* guy, but I have to do something similar to this in VIM periodically - do you have to use powershell?

Comment: Yes, this is part of a larger PS module for working with log files.  It will be used my multiple users, and there is no guarantee vim is available.

Comment: Do you want to replace a bunch of embedded carriage returns or a bunch of literal `^M`?  The file has `CRLF` line endings, right, as a normal Windows text file?  I'm trying to clarify the issue - and I can offer a native Windows solution, but not powershell in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like ^M is not being replaced by your -replace method, it's likely the replace method is trying to replace capital letter M at the beginning of the string (^).  Upon opening the file, ^M is then being interpreted as a carriage return.

Perhaps try replacing the carriage returns (^M) before displaying the contents:

```
(Get-Content C:\temp\send.log) | 
    Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "`r", ' '} | 
    Set-Content C:\temp\send.out
```

or

```
$new = Get-Content $fn | Select-Object -Last $cnt;
$new.replace("`r"," ")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, nimizen, but no joy.  My suspicion is that the ^M is translated into `r`n as the stream is being read, so processing on $new (in your example) is already too late.

Comment: Two points in addition.  First, Maybe you need to replace "`r`n"  with space.  Backtick r and backtick n become carriage return and linefeed.

Comment: Second point.  When you do a get-content of a text file with multiple lines in it, you don't get a single string.  You get an array of strings.  You seem to know this, based on the pipelining you do in your question.  But, in that case, I would think that set-content is the wrong way to add multiple lines to the output.

Comment: Oh, and a third point,  look into the variable $OFS.  This is how you control the way PS concatenates multiple texts into a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be as simple as escaping the ^ character? If you only need the last $count lines of the file you can use the -Tail parameter on Get-Content. Depending if you need to match ^M as case sensitive you might opt for -creplace instead of -replace.

```
Get-Content $inputfile -Tail $count | ForEach-Object { $_ -creplace '\^m',' ' } | Set-Content $outputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, but since you asked for a few pointers, this might help set things straight.

Try this:

```
$new = Get-Content $fn | Select-Object -Last $cnt;
$new
$new.gettype()
$new[0].gettype()
```

I expect you're going to see that $new is an array of objects, and that $new[0] is a string.  I'm going to suggest that $new[0] doesn't contain CR or LF or CRLF or anything like that.  And I'm going to suggest that, when you ask for the display of $new in its entirety, what you are getting is each string  ($new[0] followed by $new[1] ...) with CRLF inserted as a separator.

If I'm right,  replacing CR or CRLF with space isn't going to do you any good at all.  It's the CRLFs that are being inserted on output to a file that are preventing you from succeeding.

This is as far as I got towards solving your problem.